# Adding methods to a class to compare objects in Python and I keep getting error in my code

Tags: python-3.x, class

This is my assignment: Add methods to the Student class that compares two Student objects. One method should test for equality. The other methods should support the other possible comparisons. In each case, the method returns the result of the comparison of the two students' names. But for some reason, I keep getting an error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Student(object):
def __init__(self, name, number):


self.name = name
self.scores = []
for count in range(number):
  self.scores.append(0)

def getName(self):


return self.name


# method to set the score
def setScore(self, i, score):


self.scores[i - 1] = score


# method to get the score
def getScore(self, i):


return self.scores[i - 1]


# method to get the average
def getAverage(self):


return sum(self.scores) / len(self._scores)


# method to get the high score
def getHighScore(self):


  return max(self.scores)


# method to print the object in string format
def __str__(self):


return "Name: " + self.name + "\nScores: " + \
  " ".join(map(str, self.scores))


# checking for equality for the names
 def __eq__(self,other):


if self.name == other.name:
  return "Equal"
else:
  return "Not Equal"


# checking for less than in names
def __lt__(self,other):


if self.name &lt; other.name:
  return "Less than"   
else:
  return "Not less than"


# checking for greater than or equal to names
 def __ge__(self,other):


if self.name &gt;other.name:
  return "Greater than"
elif self.name == other.name:
  return "Both are equal"
else:
  return "Not greater or equal"




# main function
def main():


# creating student object
  student = Student("Sofia", 5)
  print(student)
  for i in range(1, 6):
  student.setScore(i, 100)
  print(student)


# creating student2 object
student2= Student("Dom",5)
print(student2)
for i in range(1, 6):
student2.setScore(i, 100)
print(student2)

# checking the equality methods
print(student==student2)
print(student&lt;student2)
print(student2&lt;student)
print(student&gt;=student2)




# calling the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Comment: Your code is not indented properly. Where are you attempting to "test for equality?" Which parts of the object (attributes) should be compared when testing for equality. Look at `__eq__` method in "rich comparison" methods for adding these comparison operators to classes. (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: You need to fix the indenting. Also it looks like some HTML has gotten into your code: `&lt;`. You also need to include the error you're getting. See [mre] for reference.